# Component-wise Metropolis Hastings more computationally efficient?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, markov-process, metropolis-hastings

I read in a research paper that performing the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm "per component" (i.e. in higher dimensions, instead of updating the whole state, the state is updated per component) is more computationally efficient.

I'm failing to see why this is true- surely cycling over each dimension is more computationally expensive and would take longer (e.g. if working in 100-d)?

Thanks for your help!

Here is a link to the paper - https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02789703.pdf

Comment: Would you mind to refer that paper?

Comment: Sure! I just edited my original post

Comment: Perhaps an issue with getting proposals in high dimensions with good acceptance rates? I could see how that is an issue with standard MH in high dimensions, if you use some normal distribution for proposals. If your multidimensional proposal (nearly) always gets rejected, then making a one-dimensional proposal that has some chance may help. As you say, you'd still explore the sample space rather slowly. I believe that's the circumstances where e.g. Hamiltonian Monte Carlo (implemented e.g. via the No-U-Turn-Sampler as in Stan) helps.

Comment: More efficient than what?! The comparison will depend on the calibration of the proposals in the Metropolis-within-Gibbs and in the global Metropolis versions. For instance, if the global proposal is the true target, it cannot be beaten.